# How to define where condition in resource model function for specific value? magento2

Tags: magento2, sql, resource-model

How to define condition in resource model function , i have a function for sales reporting , here it is fetching records from defined columns as given below , **i want to add condition here for status column to fetch only those status which is equals to **'closed'** in my db row**  , is that possible to define here ?

```
public function applyBaseFilters($collection)
    {
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
            ->columns([
                'period' =>'DAYNAME(created_at)',
                'total_orders' => 'COUNT(entity_id)',
                'total_items' => 'SUM(total_item_count)',
                'subtotal' => 'SUM(base_subtotal)',
                'tax' => 'SUM(base_tax_amount)',
                'status' => 'status',
                'shipping' => 'SUM(base_shipping_amount)',
                'discounts' => 'SUM(base_discount_amount)',
                'total' => 'SUM(base_grand_total)',
                'invoiced' => 'SUM(base_total_invoiced)',
                'refunded' => 'SUM(base_total_refunded)',
                'entity_id' => 'CONCAT(entity_id,\''.$this->createUniqueEntity().'\')'
            ])
        ;
    }
```

File location is **(\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `->where("'status' = 'closed'")` as follows

```
$collection->getSelect()
            ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
            ->where("'status' = 'closed'")
            ->columns([
                'period' =>'DAYNAME(created_at)',
                'total_orders' => 'COUNT(entity_id)',
                'total_items' => 'SUM(total_item_count)',
                'subtotal' => 'SUM(base_subtotal)',
                'tax' => 'SUM(base_tax_amount)',
                'status' => 'status',
                'shipping' => 'SUM(base_shipping_amount)',
                'discounts' => 'SUM(base_discount_amount)',
                'total' => 'SUM(base_grand_total)',
                'invoiced' => 'SUM(base_total_invoiced)',
                'refunded' => 'SUM(base_total_refunded)',
                'entity_id' => 'CONCAT(entity_id,\''.$this->createUniqueEntity().'\')'
            ])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i already did it :) same thing before reading your answer .....it works